# One fragment with two or more layouts and behaviours

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, architecture

I have one problem:

I need to write fragment with settings for user, but when user is `TYPE_USER` he has some other behaviour and other layout than when he is `TYPE_PREMIUM`.

I wrote interface `SettingsAction` and two implementations:

`SettingsActionForNormal` and `SettingsActionForPremium`, but I dont know, is it correctly ?

Common things for both types should be placed in fragment or in based class for `SettingsActionForNormal` and.. which implements `SettingsAction` ?

How should be code architecture when there are many types of user and they have different behaviours and layouts in many fragments ?

I cant find a good open source project with thats problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with dagger?
I would suggest that you use dagger's DI which will make you life easier for adding and removing dependancies of fragments/activities

see here http://square.github.io/dagger